# Regex pattern that ensures that atleast one character is present along with other conditions

Tags: regex, go, regex-lookarounds

I am trying to validate a string based on the three conditions below

1. It must contain a string
2. It should not contain any special characters except `.` and `-`.
3. Numbers are allowed but not necessary

I formed this regex `^(?=.*[a-zA-Z])[a-zA-Z0-9\.\- ]*$` with the help of hit and trial. And it works in all the online tools available for testing. But I am not able to use this in the code

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "regexp"
)

func main() {
    rule := regexp.MustCompile(`^(?=.*[a-zA-Z])[a-zA-Z0-9\.\- ]*$`).MatchString
    fmt.Println(rule("test_string"))
}
```

The error says

```
panic: regexp: Compile(`^(?=.*[a-zA-Z])[a-zA-Z0-9\.\- ]*$`): error parsing regexp: invalid or unsupported Perl syntax: `(?=`
```

Even though it works in other online tools. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

go does not support lookaround assertions, but you can omit the lookarounds by matching the allowed characters.

You can match a single char A-Za-z between optionally matching any of the allowed characters.

```
^[0-9. -]*[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9. -]*$
```

**Explanation**

- `^` Start of string
- `[0-9. -]*` Optionally match any of the allowed chars without a-zA-Z
- `[a-zA-Z]` Match a single char a-zA-Z
- `[a-zA-Z0-9. -]*` Optionally match any of all the allowed chars
- `$` End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/NERzlh/1)

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "regexp"
)

func main() {
    rule := regexp.MustCompile(`^[0-9. -]*[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9. -]*$`).MatchString
    fmt.Println(rule("test_string"))
    fmt.Println(rule("this is a test"))
}
```

Output

```
false
true
```